# iPhone UITableView after refresh cell separation is appear

Tags: uitableview, separator

How to refresh cell and add subview without showing separate line?
After reload cell - height is changing and in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView_ cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method I adding custom view to cell and the white separate line is appear but after scrolling TableView separate line is hidden

Comment: Can you add a picture to your description and some code?

Comment: I found out - it's wrong image.